# How to change 'S' to 's' in tpope/vim-surround - VIM

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, surround

When we are in visual mode we have to press 'S' to surround the selected text.

How can I change 'S' to 's' in [tpope/vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim

So at a glance it looks like all the mapping are made separately, depending on the use case.

You can override those in your `.vimrc`. Just beware that `s` is a default vim mapping for "substitute char".

Comment: plust1 Thank you for your reply, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out what exactly is mapped to `S` by issuing `:map S` and then bind this command to to whatever you like. To map it to `s` add a following line to your `.vimrc`

```
xmap s <Plug>VSurround
```

Comment: plus1 thank you very much for your reply, it helps me a lot.   Sorry, @guessimtoolate posted earlier.